How to transform a general single parameter quintic equation to the Bring Gerrard from without using computer algorithms?
A general quintic equation in the form $ax^5 + bx^4 + cx^3 + dx^2 + ex + f = 0$ can be transformed to principal quintic from using a quadratic Tschirnhaus transformation, $y = x^2 + mx + n$ to obtain
$y^5 + py^2 + qy + r = 0$ where coefficients of $y^4$ and $y^3$ are set to $0$.
Then we use a quartic transformation, $z = y^4 + αy^3 + βy^2 + γy + ε$, where we obtain:
$z^5 + sz + t = 0$.
Can we carry out the quadratic and quartic transformations without using computer algorithms; using pen and paper? If so, what is the method?

You can do it by hand by taking the resultant of the two polynomials (Which is a matrix relating the two polynomials.) We have the transformation $y=x^2+mx+n$ for the quintic $ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f=0$. the matrix should look like
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c & d & e & f & 0 \\
0 & a & b & c & d & e & f \\
1 & m & n-y & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & m & n-y & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & m & n-y & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & m & n-y & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & m & n-y\\
\end{vmatrix}
After finding the determinant, You should be able to collect m and n to eliminate 2 terms then after that you can re apply the same steps but for the quartic transformation, you'll need a 9x9 matrix because of the degrees of the two polynomials. The quartic transformation will eliminate 4 terms but the thing is, one of the variables is a free parameter so we can eliminate 3 terms in order to make it into it’s Bring Jerrard form.
